# SSH tunnel to a remote address

Tags: windows, ssh, tunnel

I have a VM, accessible via 192.168.56.101:22. Now I want to create a tunnel:

127.0.0.1:12345 -> www.google.com:80

where 127.0.0.1 is the IP address of the loopback interface of the VM. The host OS has a route to www.google.com and no package forwarding enabled.

Is it possible to do this solely with SSH? If yes, how?

Comment: I've assumed some stuff in my answer, if it's wrong let me know and I'll clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ssh -R 127.0.0.1:12345:www.google.com:80 username@192.168.56.101` from the host.

This will forward 127.0.0.1:12345 on the VM to www.google.com:80 over the tunnel.

Comment: Ah yes, I misread the query, the subtle difference between -L and -R is the key!

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:12345:www.google.com:80 me@192.168.56.101
```

That creates the tunnel from some workstation, through 192.168.56.101 to www.google.com

I'm not sure your question is really asking that - but that's the answer that makes most sense.  Since the VM can already reach www.google.com I'm presuming you've got a third machine (a workstation for example) that wants to reach google, via the VM.

But this creates a tunnel such that workstation is listening on port 12345, and any traffic sent to that port goes to your VM and then out to Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh  username@192.168.56.101  -L localhost:12345:google.com:80
```

Then, connect to localhost:12345 to access google.com. Also, you could use

```
ssh username@192.168.56.101  -D localhost:12345
```

to let ssh decide where to connect to (e.g. google.com:80) at the time that you connect to localhost:12345 with your application.

I believe either of those will do the trick.